# my iframe wont go fullscreen, how can i fix this?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I have a iframe pointing to another website on https://github.com/BumbleFuzzz/incog and when I open up the github-page it keeps doing a windowed thing off in the corner... how can I make it fullscreen?

Comment: There is a typo in your index.html file. The first opening of the iframe tag is not properly closed because it is missing this character `>` at line 4.

Replace `<iframe src="..."_</iframe>` with `<iframe src="..."></iframe>`.

Comment: I'm also getting a bit confused with the question. __"windowed thing off"?__ Like, is the __content not being loaded?__

I'm not sure whether you're looking for the content to be loaded fully in the iframe *(when you refer to it as the screen)*, or whether you'd like to make the iframe **THE fullscreen** on the window display.

But just in case, here is an answer to make the iframe viewport size. `<iframe style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh" src="..."></iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find it's solution with first try, you should reduce other odds.

-an example :

go your css and make your all element to this.

*{ padding : 0; margin : 0; }

if you share your code with live snippet, i can solve it fast.
an other advice : go to look 'mdn' for other details about .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).